# What visa should I apply for when attending a conference in the US?

Tags: visas, usa, pakistani-citizens, conferences

I am from Pakistan and I am doing my PhD in Italy. My research paper has been accepted for a conference in the USA. I want to participate in the conference, but I am confused about what type of visa I need.

What type of visa is required to attend a conference in the USA: a B1 or a J1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attending an academic conference counts as a "business" purpose, so you need a B-1 visa.

J-1 is for formalized study or exchange programs of longer duration than the handful of days a conference will last.